# Swift Combine Handling Errors in Flatmap

Tags: ios, swift, combine

Is there a way in the following Combine chain to handle all errors at one place ?. If I don't handle the error in flatMap, the `$text` publisher will never emit again. Thank you.

```swift
    $text
          .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
          .flatMap {
            Repository().retrieve(query: $0)
              .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
              .catch { err -> AnyPublisher<[Beer], Never> in
                self.serverError = err.displayValue
                return Just([]).eraseToAnyPublisher()
              }
          }
          .map { $0.map { ItemViewModel($0) } }
          .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
          .sink {[weak self] val in
            self?.items = val
          }.store(in: &cancellables)
```

Comment: You _are_ catching it in flatMap, that is how to do it. See the Failing Without Terminating section here https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsflatmap.html

Comment: @matt I was wondering if there is a way to handle it in the upstream publisher maybe with `replaceError([])` but that would end the publisher. Seems it can get quite complicated if I have multiple `flatMap`

Comment: Well, if you read the link I sent you to, you know the answer. If there's an error, caught or otherwise, in the main pipeline, it filters up to the publisher and it stops publishing. You could write a custom operator, I suppose, that refuses to propagate a failure up the pipeline, but there's no such native operator. Barring that, catching the failure inside the flatmap is just what you do. If you find yourself using the same sequence of operators inside multiple flatMaps, you can coalesce _them_ into a custom operator.

Comment: By the way, I don't know what you think you're up to with `self.serverError = err.displayValue` but I think it's a really bad idea. You shouldn't be running a Combine pipeline for its side effects. If you want to produce an error message, pass it down the pipeline and deal with it in the sink.

Comment: Thanks for the article @matt, It really makes sense now. I understand what you mean by not side-effecting but I want to display an error to the user but still have my denounce publisher active. If I throw that error, the denounce will complete and no longer emit.

Comment: @Jani, might be better then to return `Result<[Beer], Error>` and handle errors in the sink

Comment: @NewDev if I do that the debounce will stop working. I want the text denounces to keep working even after a repository error.

Comment: @Jani, to clarify - I meant that the Output type would be `Result<...>`, but the Failure type is still `Never`.

Comment: Oh sorry, great idea. I will try that.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you @NevDev and @matt for pushing me in the correct direction.

```swift
  lazy var publisher: AnyPublisher<Result<[ItemViewModel], RepositoryError>, Never> = {
    $text
      .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
      .flatMap {
        Repository().retrieve(query: $0)
          .map { Result.success($0.map { ItemViewModel($0) }) }
          .catch { error in Just(Result.failure(error)) }
      }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }()

  init() {
    publisher
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .sink {[weak self] value in
        switch value {
          case let .success(items): self?.items = items
          case .failure(let error): self?.serverError = error.displayValue
        }
      }
      .store(in: &cancellables)
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks good! That’s more Combine-like.